# Output of a deep neural network in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have a neural network and this is the function for it:

```py
def mlp(sizes, activation=nn.Tanh, output_activation=nn.Identity):
    # Build a feedforward neural network. outputs are the logits
    layers = []
    for j in range(len(sizes)-1):
        act = activation if j < len(sizes)-2 else output_activation
        layers += [nn.Linear(sizes[j], sizes[j+1]), act()]
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

and `sizes=[10, 20]`

My input is a tensor in the shape of `[100,1,10]` and with this network, I get a tensor as my output in the shape of `[100,20]`. What I would like to add is two more layers so that instead of a matrix as the output, I get a vector of size 20. Is this possible considering that the input includes a batch of images?

Comment: In PyTorch images are represented by tensors like: [batch_size, channels, height, width]. If you are handling images, you should adjust like this. For instance a one channel (gray) image, for batch of one, is something like: [1, 1, height, width]

Comment: Can you clarify a little something ? The network you put here transforms [100, 1, 10] into [100,1,20], not [100,20]. Then you mention that you want to convert [100,20] into a vector. So what do you mean ? Do you want [100,1,20] into [100,20] (with a view for example) or [100,20] -> [20] (with some operation like a mean over the whole batch) ?

Comment: I don't want to use view or take the mean. I would like to add one or two layers to the network so I get an output that is a vector of size 20. I was thinking about flattening the [100,20] matrix output and then adding two layers like [2000, 100] and [100,20] so I get only onevector of size 20 instead of 100 of those.